# o que significa #!/bin/bash no shell?

Tags: linux, script, bash, shell

Indica o interpretador?
ou
é o caminho completo onde o arquivo está localizado?
ou
local onde o script será salvo?
ou
qual seria interpretador dos comandos presentes no script?
ou
O diretório temporário o qual o arquivo será armazenado enquanto o script for executado?

Comment: Importante sempre usar a pesquisa antes de postar. Uma lida na [help] pode ajudar num melhor aproveitamento da plataforma e na formulação de postagens.